# Config files for mime settings

Tags: xfce, mime-types, user-default

I have an  Aweseome-wm + xfce system.

Where does `xfce4-mime-settings` stores its values? In particular as regards default apps.
The GUI values are different for me from those on `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and they have precedence over the latter.

Some defaults programs are stored in:

```
~/.config/xfce4/helpers.rc
/etc/xdg/xfce4/helpers.rc
```

But that does not include PDF types.

Comment: by GUI you mean xfce4-mime-settings? In my case xfce4-mime-settings, exo-open and thunar are all coherent mimeapps.list so I can only assume that xfce4-mime-settings is using some file related to awesome-wm or the file manager you use (if not thunar) before mimeapps.list

Comment: @MartínCanaval: Yes I meant `xfce4-mime-settings` GUI. `exo-open` and `thunar` are coherent with the GUI for me too, but  
`man exo-open` does not make it clear to me where `exo-open` takes the name of the app to open a PDF. Also, if I change the reader app in `xfce4-mime-settings`, `exo-open` updates its behaviour, so the latter seems not dictated by awesome-wm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon trial and error in a docker, I realised what follows.

`xfce4-mime-settings` reads associations in preference order from:

1. `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`
2. `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

Actual directories are affected by `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`, and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` and it is possible to have also a DE specific version of `mimeapps.list` with higher preference, such as `xfce-mimeapps.list`.
See [Association between MIME types and applications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-latest.html)

If the user modifies settings in `xfce4-mime-settings`, they are saved to `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`.

The file `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`  can be created from scratch or updated with the standard utility from freedesktop.org  [desktop-file-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/)

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

i still don't know if there is tool to  bulk-populate `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`

With respect to my question, apparent idiosyncaracies are solved by inspecting the cache (`mimeinfo.cache`).

Comment: The information might be not totally accurate, so I will not yet close the question. In particular,  I'd to find more about the generation of `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it misses subclasses. For example, `inode/mount-point` (see `/usr/share/mime/inode/mount-point.xml`) is missing in `mimeapps.list`, because it is a subclass of `inode/directory`, yet is shown seperately in `xfce4-mime-settings`.

Comment: There is a tool to bulk set default mime type apps, calle [selectdefaultapplication](https://github.com/sandsmark/selectdefaultapplication). It is listed in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_MIME_Applications#Utilities). But this tool [also misses subclasses](https://github.com/sandsmark/selectdefaultapplication/issues/10).

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but subclasses are listed under `/usr/share/mime/subclasses`

Comment: Wow talk about unchecked config file multiplication! 
All of what is needed to make a mimetype should be set with one line in /etc/mime.types or $HOME/.mime.types, yet I find myself rummaging through no less than a dozen directories and individual 40 line .xml files for each and every mimetype, and that does not include the association of mimetypes with applications.

Answer (score -2):

The file can be found at:

/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache

Comment: While this may *very tersely* answer the question of "Where does xfce4-mime-settings stores its values?" it's been flagged as low-quality because of its terseness. I'll clear the flags, but is there any chance you could add some verbiage to this answer; even make a sentence of it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it saves configuration in what is presumably a root-owned location?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: he is right. I also added what I have found in a separate answer