# Automatic generation of mimeapps.list database

Tags: configuration, mime-types, user-default

In a previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/507943/44919) I enquired about manually setting  default applications for different mime types.

Other than use tools one among [several tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications#Resource_openers), 
it boiled down to add an entry to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, which overrides system wide settings cached in  `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`. YMMV  depending on your system  [XDG Base Directory](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.7.html)
settings and compliance.

Our distros usually sport a large `mimeapps.list` (more than 50 lines in my case). While there are (GUI) tools to add/modify single entries, I didn't find any standard procedure and/or  tool to automatically generate the whole  `mimeapps.list` database.

If I delete `mimeapps.list` and install new applications,  it is not rebuilt.
So, 
*what process generates `mimeapps.list`?*

Answer (score 1):

A kind of solution, is copying `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, and change the main section name from `[MIME Cache]` to `[Default Applications]`.

Another tip is that both files can be commented with `#` (is the same parser that process `*.desktop` files).